# Notepad++: Add tab at the beginning of a multi-line match found with regex?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have text formatted like this:

```
:AGG NUMBER 1
:TYPE Alfa
any text 1
line 2 
anythihng
:END

:AGG NUMBER 2
:TYPE char
other any text 1
line 2 
:END
```

I need to add a tab character at the beginning of all lines between :TYPE and :AND.

```
:AGG NUMBER 1
:TYPE Alfa
    any text 1
    line 2 
    anythihng
:END

:AGG NUMBER 2
:TYPE char
    other any text 1
    line 2 
:END
```

How do I add tab chars with regex ?

Comment: It would help if you formulate a question in the body of the question, not just in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what : `^[^\:]\w+`

Replace with : `\t$0`

Search Mode : Regular Expression